# TCP Connection Pooling JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, connection-pooling

I found a *similar* question here: [How to implement TCP connection pooling in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735298/how-to-implement-tcp-connection-pooling-in-java)

But I see that the answers are not enough. Also, I tried other links too but all connection pooling examples were either related to DB or HTTP Connection Pooling.

Here is the situation: I have a server running using socket on some port. Now, there is a middle-ware with which clients interact and this middle-ware interacts with the TCP server to get the response. So, I wanted to create a connection pool between this  middle-ware and TCP server.

Now, here are the questions:

1. Is TCP Connection Pooling possible.
2. If it is, is there a library that does it for me? Or do I have to implement it myself?
3. If former, any link to library, docs etc. would help. If latter, any related implementation (readable and understandable) would be of help.

(I'd prefer former.)

Comment: Establishing a TCP connection is generally cheap.  Why do you need to pool connections?

Comment: The requests from client side will be very frequent. And processing for response is *not much* of work. So, establishing and closing connections all the time will be expensive. @Jason

Comment: How many connections are you establishing to the server?

Comment: @Jason, Does that matter? I'll need to make around 100-120 connections max. But, requests are frequent. So, I don't want to make and lose connections everytime.

Comment: Its more like, wherever you can save time, save it.

Comment: I don't know of any generalized java resource pool libraries, but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement one.  It may be easier to multiplex one connection though.  It scales better and it avoids the complexity of implementing a socket resource pool (e.g. connection limits).

Comment: What do you mean by multiplexing a connection? @Jason

Comment: There are a number of SO posts on multiplexed communication.  Here's one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665625/is-it-possible-to-multiplex-socket-connections) I found with a quick search.